# Roots of polynomials of the form $x^n+bx^{n-1}+c$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Solving for the roots of high degree polynomials is quite challenging, I am wondering if there are any tricks that make it easier to solve for the roots of polynomials where most of the coefficients are zero, namely polynomials of the form

$x^n+bx^{n-1}+c$

Are there any theorems about roots of such polynomials, in terms of existence of real roots for example for conditions on $b$ and $c$. We know that the roots of

$x^n−1$ are given by $e^{2\pi}k/n$.

There also appears to be special formulas for the roots of

$x^n - x -c$

Given in the below paper
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9411224.

Comment: look at the mimnimal polynomial of $1/x$